# Cisco vwlc SHA2 certificates not supported bug?

Tags: virtual-machine, wireless, cisco

I currently have an app running with a Cisco virtual Wireless Lan Controller, all works fine except we get some error messages regarding SHA1 certificates, when I'm looking for SHA2 support the cisco release notes tell me that SHA2 certificates are not supported, even in the latest 8.2.100.0 release. Can anyone confirm this, or better yet does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported on a virtual WLC:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/release/notes/crn82.html#pgfId-1319001